Chrome Theming: How do I remove or change the color and width of the dividers between tabs?
I've installed a theme that I like, but I absolutely hate the thick dividers between each tab when I have a lot of tabs open.

I'd ideally like to:

Change their width to 1px
Change the color
Optionally just completely remove them.

Can anyone show me how to edit my theme to accomplish this? My Google-Fu produced no results.
Any help greatly appreciated.

How are we supposed to help without knowing what theme you have installed?

I think this is part of the UI unfortunately. I'm not a Chrome themes expert, so correct me if I'm wrong, because I'm also interested in knowing that, but it seem that the separator color is being controlled by the toolbar color underneath it. You can even see it in your own screenshot above - the separator color matches the toolbar color underneath it and the color of the currently active tab.
You can find out how to access the source code (the manifest.json) file of your currently installed theme for your operating system on the internet.
Then you can find some general information about theme building and links to all available theme options here, but the relevant bits are these:
{
  "theme": {
    "colors": {
      // the default background of the tabs and the tab bar as a whole
      "frame": [ 167, 171, 183 ],
      // the color of the toolbar -
      // that entire line plus the color of the active tab
      // it also controls the separator color between tabs
      "toolbar": [ 217, 218, 223 ]
    }
  }
}

To test your updated theme you have to load it as unpacked extension using the Load Unpacked button in chrome://extensions. Make sure that the Developer mode is also turned on.
